# Unity jittery movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following simple lines of code that moves the camera similar to the camera movement in zig zag game ( moving vertically forever ). I also have very simple cube structure similar to zig zag game. In original zig zag game, there is no jittery movement in iPad Mini. But the below lines of code causing jittery movement..

- I tried project settings->Time setting to 0.03 and targetFrameRate to
- Tried in Update
- Tried in FixedUpdate
- Tried in LateUpdate...

But none works, I can always reproduce the jittery movement

```
void Update() {
float calculatedSpeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate( direction * calculatedSpeed);                  
    }



void LateUpdate() {
        if( !dead ) {
            Vector3 position = transform.position;
            float halfX = position.x;
            float halfZ = position.z;
            float distance = Vector3.Distance (position, playerInitPosition);
            Vector3 newPos = Main.Instance.camReference.forward * distance;
            Main.Instance.camReference.position = newPos;               
        }
    }
```

In Update, transform.position updates player move in zig zag pattern,
In LateUpdate, camera moves vertically based on the distance the player moves

You can check android game play here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.angryeggstudio.games.zigzagpenguin

This smoothness is not there in iPad Mini

Update 1:
Android that works without any flaw...its smooth and fine :
[image]

iPad Mini that has jittery movement:

[image]

Note: Check the cube edges while camera moves... you can spot its jittery movement in iPad Mini...

Comment: What value is your speed variable?

Comment: Speed set to 8...It increases to 9, 10,11 and 12 max

Comment: Do the positions of your objects are very close or very far from the world origin?

Comment: It's same as zig zag.. no difference from that game.  Moreover I have no issues in Android devices

Comment: If your camera moves only vertically but player moves zig-zag pattern, should you only take "vertical" component of the distance vector?

Comment: I just wanted to replicate the same camera movement as in zig zag game.. for that specifc logic, vertical component is enough... My only problem is in ipad mini...

Comment: I have achieved the same game play and camera movement as zig zag game... It's just the jitter causing issues... It's so minute the jittery movement

Comment: A gif or a video would be helpful. Also there is not enough information to say what causes the issue. Have you tried to move any other objects using transform.Translate or just setting transform.position? Have you tried rigidbody methods like velocity AddForce, etc...
is the gameObject's movement jittery too, or is only the camera's?

Comment: gif attached for reference...

Comment: Add force won't work for this particular need